# Determine the type of an input

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

The challenge is simple: Determine the type of an input, and output an identifier telling what type it is.

- "UI", Unsigned integer: `0`, `1`,`34`, `111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`
- "SI", Signed integer: `+0`, `+1`, `+42`, `-1`, `-3`, `-111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`
- "UD", Unsigned decimal: `0.0`, `1.23`, `1234.1234`
- "SD", Signed decimal: `-0.0`, `+0.0`, `-1.235`
- "LE", Letter: `a`-`z` and `A`-`Z`
- "SY", Symbol: ASCII code points: `[32-47, 58-64, 91-96, 123-126]` (i.e. all characters except numbers and letters)
- "ST", String: Two or more character that can't be parsed as any of the above number formats

**Rules:**

- The input will be 1-99 characters long
- The input will only contain printable ASCII characters, code points: 32-126.
- The output should be the two identifier letters as defined above (UI, SI ...)
- Standard I/O rules apply

**Examples:**

```
UI:
0
01
34
12938219383278319086135768712319838871631827319218923

SI:
-0
+01
+1
-123
+123

UD:
0.0
3.1415
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757

SD:
+0.0
-3.1415
+2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757

LE:
a
k
L
Z

SY:
@
"
+
-

ST:
Hello, World!
f2!"
+23df
1234A
'"!
.012
1.
UI
+-1
5+3
```

Comment: Can `SY` be more than one character?

Comment: I would not consider `111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` to be of integer type.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman sy is only one character.

Comment: So we take the input as a string?

Comment: @Matt, It might not be a `uint8` or `int64`, but it's definitely an [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).

Comment: Here +45 is not signed it is PI positive integer (as 45) ... Your classification can not be so easy to write in Axiom. "signed integer" here and in C language too are called "int" or "INT"

Comment: @RosLuP it's not meant to be the type your language interprets it as. You should simply output two characters based on the input string/number.

Comment: +38 is not signed it is unsigned.

Comment: @RosLuP I'm not sure you get the point of this challenge. It doesn't matter how it's interpreted in some language, or what the normal naming convention for numbers is. In **this challenge** "signed" is defined as: "There's a plus or minus sign followed by a number". You may disregard the words signed and unsigned doesn't actually affect the challenge, you should output a two character string based on some input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pyth - 47 bytes

Can prolly golf a few bytes off with some slicing tricks.

```
.x-+?@z"+-"\S\U?@z\.\D\Isz?!tz?}rzZG"LE""SY""ST
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.x-%2B%3F%40z%22%2B-%22%5CS%5CU%3F%40z%5C.%5CD%5CIsz%3F%21tz%3F%7DrzZG%22LE%22%22SY%22%22ST&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A01%0A34%0A12938219383278319086135768712319838871631827319218923%0A-0%0A%2B01%0A%2B1%0A-123%0A%2B123%0A0.0%0A3.1415%0A2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757%0A%2B0.0%0A-3.1415%0A%2B2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757%0Aa%0Ak%0AL%0AZ%0A%40%0A%22%0A%2B%0A-%0AHello%2C+World%21%0Af2%21%22%0A%2B23df%0A1234A%0A%27%22%21%0A.012%0A1.%0AUI%0A%2B-1%0A5%2B3&debug=0).

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 99

```js
x=>(z=x.match(/^([+-])?\d+(\.\d+)?$/))?'SU'[+!z[1]]+'DI'[+!z[2]]:x[1]?'ST':parseInt(x,36)?'LE':'SY'
```

**Test**

```js
f=x=>(z=x.match(/^([+-])?\d+(\.\d+)?$/))?'SU'[+!z[1]]+'DI'[+!z[2]]:x[1]?'ST':parseInt(x,36)?'LE':'SY'

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;console.log(['0','01','34','12938219383278319086135768712319838871631827319218923'].map(x=>f(x)+' '+x).join`\n`)
;console.log(['-0','+01','+1','-123','+123'].map(x=>f(x)+' '+x).join`\n`)
;console.log(['0.0','3.1415','2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757'].map(x=>f(x)+' '+x).join`\n`)
;console.log(['+0.0','-3.1415','+2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757'].map(x=>f(x)+' '+x).join`\n`)
;console.log([...'akLZ'].map(x=>f(x)+' '+x).join`\n`)
;console.log([...'@"+-'].map(x=>f(x)+' '+x).join`\n`)
;console.log(['Hello, World!','f2!"','+23df','1234A',`'"!`,'.012','1.','UI','+-1','5+3'].map(x=>f(x)+' '+x).join`\n`)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: I was pretty sure that someone would be able to optimise for shared cases but I like your use of parseInt to detect letters.

Comment: The first ( ) in your regex is not necessary

Comment: @Awashi it is necessary as I need a capture group for the sign to differentiate S or U.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes no, it could be `(\+|-)` but no bytes saved

Answer (score 3):

## Turing Machine Code, 1544 bytes

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?5ef35b8f266f83c679eb72a62b9ac417)

```
0 + _ r s
0 - _ r s
0 0 _ r u
0 1 _ r u
0 2 _ r u
0 3 _ r u
0 4 _ r u
0 5 _ r u
0 6 _ r u
0 7 _ r u
0 8 _ r u
0 9 _ r u
0 a _ r l
0 b _ r l
0 c _ r l
0 d _ r l
0 e _ r l
0 f _ r l
0 g _ r l
0 h _ r l
0 i _ r l
0 j _ r l
0 k _ r l
0 l _ r l
0 m _ r l
0 n _ r l
0 o _ r l
0 p _ r l
0 q _ r l
0 r _ r l
0 s _ r l
0 t _ r l
0 u _ r l
0 v _ r l
0 w _ r l
0 x _ r l
0 y _ r l
0 z _ r l
0 A _ r l
0 B _ r l
0 C _ r l
0 D _ r l
0 E _ r l
0 F _ r l
0 G _ r l
0 H _ r l
0 I _ r l
0 J _ r l
0 K _ r l
0 L _ r l
0 M _ r l
0 N _ r l
0 O _ r l
0 P _ r l
0 Q _ r l
0 R _ r l
0 S _ r l
0 T _ r l
0 U _ r l
0 V _ r l
0 W _ r l
0 X _ r l
0 Y _ r l
0 Z _ r l
0 * _ r y
s 0 _ r s
s 1 _ r s
s 2 _ r s
s 3 _ r s
s 4 _ r s
s 5 _ r s
s 6 _ r s
s 7 _ r s
s 8 _ r s
s 9 _ r s
s . _ r d
s _ _ r i
s * _ r T
u 0 _ r u
u 1 _ r u
u 2 _ r u
u 3 _ r u
u 4 _ r u
u 5 _ r u
u 6 _ r u
u 7 _ r u
u 8 _ r u
u 9 _ r u
u . _ r D
u _ _ r I
u * _ r T
l _ _ r L
l * _ r T
y _ _ r S
y * _ r T
d 0 _ r d
d 1 _ r d
d 2 _ r d
d 3 _ r d
d 4 _ r d
d 5 _ r d
d 6 _ r d
d 7 _ r d
d 8 _ r d
d 9 _ r d
d _ _ r e
d * _ r T
i 0 _ r i
i 1 _ r i
i 2 _ r i
i 3 _ r i
i 4 _ r i
i 5 _ r i
i 6 _ r i
i 7 _ r i
i 8 _ r i
i 9 _ r i
i _ _ r j
i * _ r T
D 0 _ r D
D 1 _ r D
D 2 _ r D
D 3 _ r D
D 4 _ r D
D 5 _ r D
D 6 _ r D
D 7 _ r D
D 8 _ r D
D 9 _ r D
D _ _ r E
D * _ r T
I 0 _ r I
I 1 _ r I
I 2 _ r I
I 3 _ r I
I 4 _ r I
I 5 _ r I
I 6 _ r I
I 7 _ r I
I 8 _ r I
I 9 _ r I
I _ _ r J
I * _ r T
L * L r M
M * E r halt
S * S r Y
Y * Y r halt
e * S r f
f * D r halt
j * S r k
k * I r halt
E * U r f
J * U r k
T _ S r U
T * _ r T
U * T r halt
```

Comment: Please include a fully-golfed version of the code. If the whitespace cannot be removed, it must be counted in the byte count.

Comment: Looks like it can not be removed, the program does not work properly without spaces between the symbols.

Comment: It doesn't seem to classify "+-1" (from the examples) as a ST.

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, <s>98</s> 97 bytes

A nice way to practise my regex skills indeed.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=Xig_IVsrLV0_XGQrKFwuXGQrKT8kKS4uKwpTVApeKFsrLV0_KVxkKyQKJDFVSQpeKFsrLV0_KVxkK1wuXGQrJAokMVVECmlgXlthLXpdJApMRQpeLiQKU1kKWystXVUKUw&input=eg)

```
^(?![+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$)..+
ST
^([+-]?)\d+$
$1UI
^([+-]?)\d+\.\d+$
$1UD
i`^[a-z]$
LE
^.$
SY
[+-]U
S
```

Comment: You can change `^[a-zA-Z]$` to `i\`^[a-z]$` to save one byte

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 157 bytes

[Try it online!](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)

Golfed:

```
n=(...)m=string.match s=m(n,"^[+-]")and"S"or"U"print(m(n,"^[+-]?%d+%.%d+$")and s.."D"or m(n,"^[+-]?%d+")and s.."I"or m(n,"^%w$")and"LE"or#n==1 and"SY"or"ST")
```

Ungolfed:

```
n = "2.718281828459045"

s = n:sub(1,1):match("[+-]") and "S" or "U"

if n:match("^[+-]?%d+%.%d+$") then
    print(s.."D")
elseif n:match("^[+-]?%d+") then
    print(s.."I")
elseif n:match("^%w$") then
    print("LE")
elseif #n==1 then
    print("SY")
else
    print("ST")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>125</s> 120 bytes

```
s=>"UISIUDSDLESYST".substr(s.match(/^((\d+)|([+-]\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)|([+-]\d+\.\d+)|([A-Z])|(.)|(.*))$/i).indexOf(s,2)*2-4,2)
```

Alternative version, also 120 bytes:

```
s=>"STUISIUDSDLESY".substr(s.match(/^(?:(\d+)|([+-]\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)|([+-]\d+\.\d+)|([A-Z])|(.)|.*)$/i).lastIndexOf(s)*2,2)
```

Comment: Surely the regex can be golfed with a regex `eval(\`/regex/\`)` constructor + template strings

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 192 bytes

```
String t(String v){for(String[]x:new String[][]{{"\\d+","UI"},{"[-+]\\d+","SI"},{"\\d+\\.\\d+","UD"},{"[-+]\\d+\\.\\d+","SD"}})if(v.matches(x[0]))return x[1];return (v.length()==1?"SY":"ST");}
```

Comment: `return (v.length()==1?"SY":"ST");` can be `return v.length()<2?"SY":"ST";` (-3 bytes) Or it can be this: `String t(String v){for(String x:"UI\\d+;SI[-+]\\d+;UD\\d+\\.\\d+;SD[-+]\\d+\\.\\d+".split(";"))if(v.matches(x.substring(2)))return x.substring(0,2);return v.length()<2?"SY":"ST";}` (**179 bytes**) And in addition you could change `String t(String v)` to `v->` when you use a Java 8 lambda.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 138 bytes

I tried to use a `replace` to be more "fancy".

This creates an anonymous function that returns the string of the type.

```
s=>s.replace(/^((([+-])?(\d+)(\.\d+)?)|([a-z])|([ -~])|([^\0]*))$/i,(_,a,b,c,d,e,f,g)=>b?(c?'S':'U')+(e?'D':'I'):(f?'LE':'S'+(g?'Y':'T')))
```

Any tips to improving this will be entirely welcome.

Comment: `1.` should be `ST`, not `UD`. Change your `\d*` to `\d+`

Comment: @edc65 How? That's a decimal. That is the same as `1.0`.

Comment: It could be valid or not (I don't write `1.` instead of `1`) BUT It's not your choice or mine: there are the test cases

Comment: @edc65 You're right. I skipped the VERY huge list. I've fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5 - <strike>241</strike> 240 bytes:

(*Saved 1 byte thanks to @CatsAreFluffy*)

```
import re
def r(g):
 y={'^\d+$':'UI','^[+-]\d+$':'SI','^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$':'UD','[+-](?=[0-9]\d*(\.\d+))':'SD','[a-zA-Z]+':'LE','^[^A-Za-z0-9]+$':'SY'};d=[y[i]for i in list(y.keys())if re.match(i,g)]
 if len(d)>0:return d[0]
 else:return'ST'
```

It may be a bit long, but does the job pretty much perfectly. This was a really good way to improve my regular expression skills. Thanks for the challenge. :) I will try and shorten it more if I can.

Comment: You can move _import re_ to outside the function to save a space. (Stupid iPad keyboard with no backticks)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Yeah, I did not think of that. Thank you! :)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy: Actually, the iOS keyboard _does_ allow backticks! I found this out the other day when needing to write markdown using my iPhone :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133673/is-there-a-way-to-enter-back-tick-backtick-on-so-when-using-ipad-or-iphone

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Nice! That's good to know.

Comment: Also `len(d)>0`==`d>[]`

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl 414 Bytes

ungolfed implementation, readable:

```
proc a b {
  if {[string index $b 0] eq "+" || [string index $b 0] eq "-"} {
    set c S
  } elseif {[string match {[A-Za-z]} $b]} {
    return LE
  } elseif {[regexp {^(?![+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$)..+} $b]} {
    return ST
  } elseif {[regexp {[^a-zA-Z0-9.]} $b]} {
    return SY
  } else {
    set c U
  }
  if {[string match *.* $b]} {
    return $c\U
  } else {
    return $c\I
  }
}
puts [a $argv]
```